# Wordpress change text of add to cart button based on product variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I need to change the text of the "add to cart" button based on the product variables. For example I have created two variables "reservation" and "direct purchase". I would like that when the person selects the reservation the text of button change from "add to cart" to "book". Is this possible? thanks

Comment: Yes it is, but without any provided code in your question this is just too broad. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

You can change cart text by a change of category. if you want to change cart text by-product, you can add a product id.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
function bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $product_cat = $term->name;
            break;}
 switch($product_cat){
    case 'category1';
        return 'Category 1 button text'; break;
    case 'category2';
        return 'Category 2 button text'; break;
     default;
        return 'Default button text when no match found'; break;
}
}
```